# Wordpress own carousal showing 10 items but there are total 17 items in loop

Tags: php, wordpress, owl-carousel

I have a wordpress site. And I have implemented owl carousal. There are total 17 items in loop. But carousal showing 10. If I `<pre></pre>` inside the loop, then all 17 shows. What should I do?

> http://crucialappconcepts.com/#portfolio

I have this script at the end of my page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myCarousel1.carousel').owlCarousel({
    items:1,
    loop:true,
    margin:0,
    autoHeight:true
    });

  });
</script>
```

AND MY **HTML** CODE

```
<!-- Portfolio Section Starts -->  
<?php $posts = get_posts(array(
  'post_type'   => 'portfolio_post',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => 0,
  'fields' => 'ids'
  )
);
// echo '<pre>';
// print_r($posts);
// echo '</pre>';

foreach($posts as $p){

  $portfolio_color_picker1 = get_post_meta($p,"portfolio-color_picker_1",true);
  $portfolio_color_picker2 = get_post_meta($p,"portfolio-color_picker-2",true);
  $contact_color_picker1 = get_post_meta($p,"contact-color_picker-1",true);
  $contact_color_picker2 = get_post_meta($p,"portfolio-color_picker-2",true);
  $google_play_store_label = get_post_meta($p,"google_play_store_label",true);
  $google_play_store_url = get_post_meta($p,"google_play_store_url",true);
  $apple_store_label = get_post_meta($p,"apple_store_label",true);
  $apple_store_url = get_post_meta($p,"apple_store_url",true);
  $google_sub_title = get_post_meta($p,"google_sub_title",true);


                            //echo $name = get_post_meta($p,"we-color_picker-1",true);
                            //do whatever you want with it
}
?>
<?php $background = of_get_option('business_portfolio_colorpicker', true ) ;
$img = $background['image']; ?>
<section id="portfolio" class="portfolio-section" style="background:<?php if( $background['color'] ) echo $background['color']; else if($background['image']) echo 'url('.$img.')'; ?>">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 portfolio-inner">


        <?php 
        $backgroundtitle    = of_get_option('business_portfolio_title_colorpicker', true );
        $backgroundsubtitle = of_get_option('business_portfolio_subtitle_colorpicker', true );  
        ?>
        <h1 style="color : <?php echo $backgroundtitle; ?>"><?php echo of_get_option('business_portfolio_title',true); ?></h1>
        <h2 style="color :<?php echo $backgroundsubtitle; ?> "><?php echo of_get_option('business_portfolio_subtitle',true); ?></h2> 
        <section id="myCarousel1" class="carousel slide">
         <?php    $content          = of_get_option('business_portfolio_content_colorpicker', true );
         ?>   <style type="text/css">
         .vk_content p{
          color : <?php echo $content.' !important';  ?>;
        }
      </style>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
      <?php  $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio_post', 'post_status'=>'publish','order'=> 'ASC', ) );
      while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
      ?>
        <div class="items-portfolio">  
          <div class="text-center bs-ft">
           <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php echo the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?> </a>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-12 technical-features">
          <?php   $content_title    = of_get_option('business_portfolio_content_title_colorpicker', true );
          $content_subtitle = of_get_option('business_portfolio_content_subtitle_colorpicker', true );  

          ?>
            <h3 style="color : <?php echo $content_title; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
     <!--<h4>iOS - 7Objectivle - CXcodePush - Notification Integration - Social Media Integration - oAuth iOS 7 Maps
     <br>In App Purchase Integration</h4>-->
            <h4 style="color : <?php echo $content_subtitle; ?>"><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "_tech_feature", true); ?></h4>



            <div class="vk_content"><?php the_content();?></div>     
            <div class="button-container">
              <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "_google_play_store", true);  ?>">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/images/button-bg-1.png" alt="">play store</button>
              </a>
              <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "_apple_store", true);?>">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/images/button-bg-2.png" alt="">apple store</button>
              </a>
            </div>

        </div>
      </div> 
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query();?>
  </div>
</section>
</div>       
</div> 
</div>
</section>
<!-- ======= End Slider Section  ======== -->           
</div>        
</div>
</div>
</section>
<!-- End Portfolio Section -->
```

Comment: How are you generating the items?

Comment: set posts_per_page to -1 to display all items and check

Comment: as you have set `posts_per_page => 0` so by default it is taking `posts_per_page` data form you `wp_options` table. You have to set `posts_per_page => -1` or `17` to get the desired outpot.

Comment: In the loop, there are already 17 coming. I tried to set it to -1 but it is still now wotking

Comment: @AliZia did you ultimately resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try adding `'posts_per_page' => -1` to your query params in wp_query?

So it would look like this:

`<?php  $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio_post', 'post_status'=>'publish','order'=> 'ASC','posts_per_page' => -1) );`

**Update**

Alternatively, you can set nopaging to true.

`'nopaging' => true`

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters

Comment: Hi Judd. I already tried this. The issue is that $posts already has 16 elements inside it, but maybe there is carousal limit?

Comment: When I accessed the page and disabled javascript, so that owlcarousel did not run at all, there were only 10 `.items-portfolio` elements in the `.carousel` div. This indicates that the issue is with wordpress, not with owlcarousel.

Comment: The one thing that I am wondering at the moment is why the `$posts` query you are running at the top of your html file and the `$loop` query you are running below have different parameters. Have you checked that both return all 17 items if you `print_r` them?

Comment: Hi @AliZia, Adding the `'posts_per_page'=>-1` fixed it for me. Did you resolve this issue? I tried out your loops on my local wordpress install. The `$loop` loop, which is the one you are using, displays only 10 results for me.

Comment: Yes I tried all. When I print_r my variable, it displays 17 results but when I comment it, it shows only 10 :(

Comment: I just want to confirm that you know that you have two separate loop queries in this code. The second is the one you are using to generate the slides.